# Find `n` distinct elements in list with duplicates, == is okay, === is not

Tags: python, list, sample, distinct-values

I am trying to implement a differential evolution optimization algorithm and I need a way to take from a list distinct entities. They can be the same values, but can't be the same entities.

```py
solutions = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(30)] \
  for _ in range(100)]
for base_agent in solutions:
  agents = []
  while len(agents) < 3:
    p = solutions[random.randint(0, len(solutions))]
    if p in agents or p is base_agent:
      continue
    else:
      agents.add(p)
  if base_agent in agents \
    or agents[0] is agents[1] \
    or agents[1] is agents[2] \
    or agents[2] is agents[0]:
      print("Bad execution")
      exit(1)
print("Correct execution")
```

This is the (non-working) general idea of what I'm after.

I want `base_agent` to not be in `agents`, and I want `agents` to contain no duplicate entries. Entries can be the same value (e.g. they can `==`), but they cannot be the same entity (e.g. they cannot `===`). `agents` should have 3 elements within at the end of this while loop.

`random.sample` can give me, well, a random sample from a list, but it will still possibly include `base_agent`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `base_agent` is, at some point, every element in `solutions`. Are you saying you want a `base_agent` and also three different agents on each loop through the outer loop?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code doesn't run, and you haven't shown an error case.

Comment: It seems that you want 3 unique elements from a given population.  Use `set` or any other method to de-duplicate your list, remove `base_agent`, and take a `sample` of 3 elements from that.

Comment: @Prune: I'm not sure a `set` will work, since they seem to think it possible that there could be agents that are equal, but not the same identity, and they should be treated differently on some level. That said, they use a `set` for `agents` in their code, so it's unclear if the identity issue only applies to `base_agent` compared to all other agents, while the other agents can count as duplicates of each other to dedupe the three agents paired with the `base_agent`. If `base_agent is 1`, maybe `agents` can include `True` (which is distinct from `1`), but not `1.0` as well (`True == 1.0`).

Comment: @Prune: To be clear, not saying you're wrong. If the set of all possible agents if `[1,1,1,2,3,4]` (where all numbers are assumed different identities, even if CPython makes them singletons), they need to make it clear if the odds of a `1` appearing in the result should be dramatically higher than the odds of any other number, and whether more than one `1` can be included in the result at all (pre-converting to `set` works if the answer to both questions is "No", but doesn't work if the answer to either is "Yes").

Comment: @ShadowRanger for any given `base_agent`, `agents` is three other distinct values from `solutions`. `agents` is reinitialized after every for loop iteration.

Comment: @gator: Right, so your existing code doesn't work, because the `in` test will not allow two separate values that compare equal under `==` to both be selected, right? Thus why `random.sample` is desirable, since it's purely position based, it doesn't compare by value at all. If so, my answer does what's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest code is to just use `random.sample`, excluding the single element you're trying to avoid. Sure, it involves slicing out all elements save the `base_element`, but `O(n²)` work isn't all that much of a problem when `n` is only 30:

```
import random

for i, base_agent in enumerate(solutions):
    agents = random.sample(solutions[:i] + solutions[i+1:], 3)
    # Do stuff with base_agent which is distinct from all elements of agents
```

If you really hate slicing or using index values at all, you can do cheesy hacks with `itertools.combinations` to make it generate all the values that don't match the current `base_agent` for you:

```
import random
from itertools import combinations

for base_agent, other_agents in zip(solutions, combinations(reversed(solutions), len(solutions) - 1)):
    agents = random.sample(other_agents, 3)
```

Making combinations of "all but one element", using `solutions` in reverse order means each output from `combinations` is all the elements but the one you get on each iteration over `solutions`, so no slicing is needed.

Answer (score -1):

`is` is the python operator for "distinct elements". Though, not exactly like JavaScripts `===`, what `is` does is compares the memory address.

Comment: I don't think the OP ever said they thought of `===` in the JavaScript sense; they seem to use it to mean the same thing as Python's `is`, an identity test, not JS's weirdo type-strict equality test.